# Resource Policy For API Gateway, Cognito Identity Pool only access

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have been trying to get a cognito identity pool that authenticates with salesforce, to create temporary credentials that will allow my javascript application to execute an api gateway route.

I have come to the point where I am able to successfully log a user in through salesforce, get the secret key, session token, access key genrated by cognito identity pools, but when I go make the execution call on the api gateway, it always fails with the following error:

```
 {
  "Message":
      "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute- 
      api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:us-east- 
      1:********2162:xz33s93f9s/test/GET/helloworld"
 }
```

I believe the issue is with the policy setup I have added to the API Gateway:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::********2162:role/salesforce_login"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:********2162:xz33s93f9s/test/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My latest attempt was making the Principal equal role arn that users are authenticated too. But I have also attempted making it equal to the following with no success:

```
 "Principal": {
      "Federated": "login.salesforce.com"
 }
```

If I change the policy to be:

```
 "Principal": {
      "AWS": "*"
 }
```

the http request is performed successfully. So I am guessing I am either authenticating wrong, or my policy is wrong.

Here is my Role for users that become authenticated:

**role/salesforce_login**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "apigateway:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:apigateway:*::*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:*",
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

If my policies are not the issue then perhaps I am not making the http request properly and here is my code for that:

```
    var params = {
        'IdentityPoolId': pool_id,
        'Logins': logins,
        'RoleArn': ' "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::********2162:role/salesforce_login"'
    };
    // Amazon Cognito region
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

    // Initialize CognitoIdentityCredentials
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(params);
    console.log("Completed Setup")
    // Cognito credentials 
    AWS.config.credentials.get(function (err) {
        if (err) {  // an error occurred
            printMessage(err);
            console.log(err)
        }else{      // successful response
            console.log("we here")
            console.log("A KEY: "+  AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId)
            console.log("S KEY: "+  AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey)
            console.log("SESSION TOKEN: "+ AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken)
                var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
                    // Credentials will be available when this function is called.
                    accessKey : AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
                     secretKey : AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
                    sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken
                });
                var params = {
                // This is where any modeled request parameters should be added.
                // The key is the parameter name, as it is defined in the API in API Gateway.
                  'uid': '34567'
                };
                var body = {
                  // This is where you define the body of the request,
                    'uid' : '1234'
                };
                var additionalParams = {
                  // If there are any unmodeled query parameters or headers that must be
                  //   sent with the request, add them here.
                  headers: {
                      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                  },
                  queryParams: {
                  }
                };
                apigClient.helloworldGet(params, body, additionalParams)
                    .then(function(result){
                      // Add success callback code here.
                      console.log("SUCCESS")
                      console.log(result)
                    }).catch( function(result){
                      // Add error callback code here.
                      console.log("FAIL")
                      console.log(result)
                    });

        }
    });      
}
```

Is the issue with my code? The policy? any wisdom would be appreciated :)

Comment: **NOTE:** all account ids and api id numbers where changed for security purposes.

Comment: I am having the exact issue. How did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: @Robie apologies, I left the company where I had done this at and it's been so long I don't remember the exact solution. I remember the issue being the policy set up on aws api gateway.  I just don't remember what I had changed it to. I hope you were able to figure it out!